# filter multiple array of object in which based on contractNumber finding average it's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In multiple object of Array there is repeated number of contractNumber in each object but I am trying to find the average value of its contractNumber

```
  var vendorArr=[{
     "contractNumber":5258,
     "monthId":0,
     "value":2},
      {
        "contractNumber":5258,
        "monthId":2,
        "value":3
      },{
        "contractNumber":5258,
        "monthId":3,
        "value":3

     },
     {
     "contractNumber":5656,
     "monthId":0,
     "value":3
     },
     {
    "contractNumber":5656,
    "monthId":1,
    "value":4
     },
     {
    "contractNumber":5656,
    "monthId":2,
    "value":4
    }
     ];
     for(var i=0;i<vendorArr.length;i++){
      }
```

Can we find every unique contractNumber corresponding average of its value?
I am trying to finding every contractNumber and it value Average and pushing to separate Array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may appreciate the guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [how to create a good Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a two step approach, one is to collect the data for the average and the second is to get the result in an array with `contractNumber` and the average.

This proposal works with a hash table where the data gets collected an an array for the result where an object keeps the `contractNumber` and the average. This gets an update on every iteration of the given data.

```js
var data = [{ contractNumber: 5258, monthId: 0, value: 2 }, { contractNumber: 5258, monthId: 2, value: 3 }, { contractNumber: 5258, monthId: 3, value: 3 }, { contractNumber: 5656, monthId: 0, value: 3 }, { contractNumber: 5656, monthId: 1, value: 4 }, { contractNumber: 5656, monthId: 2, value: 4 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(({ contractNumber, value }) => {
    hash[contractNumber] = hash[contractNumber] || { index: result.push({ contractNumber, average: 0 }) - 1, sum: 0, count: 0 };
    hash[contractNumber].sum += value;
    result[hash[contractNumber].index].average = hash[contractNumber].sum / ++hash[contractNumber].count;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array reduce function to sum value for each `contractNumber` and create a new key `count`.To calculate the average divide the value by count

```js
var vendorArr = [{
    "contractNumber": 5258,
    "monthId": 0,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "contractNumber": 5258,
    "monthId": 2,
    "value": 3
  }, {
    "contractNumber": 5258,
    "monthId": 3,
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "contractNumber": 5656,
    "monthId": 0,
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "contractNumber": 5656,
    "monthId": 1,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "contractNumber": 5656,
    "monthId": 2,
    "value": 4
  }
];
var m = vendorArr.reduce(function(res, item) {
  if (!res[item.contractNumber]) {
    res[item.contractNumber] = {
      value: 0,
      count: 0
    };
  };
  res[item.contractNumber].value = res[item.contractNumber].value + item.value;
  res[item.contractNumber].count += 1;

  return res;
}, {});


function calAvg(contractNumber) {

  return m[contractNumber].value / m[contractNumber].count

}

console.log(calAvg(5656))
```

Comment: m trying to find every unique contractNumber average of property value of object..thanks for reply

Comment: like contractNumber is 5258 and its value is 2,next object  sane contractNumber but value is different ,so m finding ervery contractnumber average value

Comment: `every unique contractNumber average of property value of object` that is what this code is doing. It will find value of every `contractNumber ` and will find average of its value

Comment: There are three objects with same contractNumber  5656, the total of its value is 11 and there are three occurrence of `contractNumber  5656`, so 11/3 is 3.66

Answer (score 1):

I would reindex the contracts by their `contractNumber` then find the averages of their contract values.

```js
const vendorArr = [{contractNumber:5258,monthId:0,value:2},{contractNumber:5258,monthId:2,value:3},{contractNumber:5258,monthId:3,value:3},{contractNumber:5656,monthId:0,value:3},{contractNumber:5656,monthId:1,value:4},{contractNumber:5656,monthId:2,value:4}]

const findAverageContractValue = contracts => {
  const contractAverages = {}
  // re index the contracts by their `contractNumber`
  const contractsByNumber = contracts.reduce((acc, contract) => {
    if (typeof acc[contract.contractNumber] === 'undefined') {
      acc[contract.contractNumber] = []
    }
    acc[contract.contractNumber].push(contract)
    return acc
  }, {})
  
  // iterate over each type of contract
  Object.keys(contractsByNumber).forEach(contractId => {
    const contracts = contractsByNumber[contractId]
    // add the average to the contracts object
    contractAverages[contractId] =
      contracts.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x.value, 0) / contracts.length
  })
  
  return contractAverages
}
 
console.log(
  findAverageContractValue(vendorArr)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```